# How to set max map scale for a layer?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, visual-studio, wpf, arcgis-api-wpf

How can I set the maximum scale for a layer? Sometimes the layer is not visible (it disappear), when the map scale is >= 1:250000. I'd like to set it on max 1:125000.

This code does not work:

```
    Map.Layers["LB"].MaximumResolution = 125000.0;
```

I'm developing in visual studio with C# (WPF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*MaximumResolution* is not a property of *any* object in ArcObjects, did you just make that up?

If you want to set the maximum display scale of a layer you need to be using [MaximumScale](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-cpp/componenthelp/index.html#//00050000076q000000) of the ILayer interface.

Comment: You can find MaximumResolution in ESRI.ArcGIS.Client. There is:     public double MinimumResolution { get; set; }

Comment: Interesting when I searched for this property in the arcobjects api it did not find it. But you are right it is in the silverlight Web api. Are you creating some sort of Web application?

Comment: I'm working on a desktop application

Comment: Well that may be your problem, although I have never worked WPF. You would typically get a handle on a layer via IMap and change the properties of the layer, both these interfaces come from the _ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto_ namespace not _ESRI.ArcGIS.Client_